# theme RTL make big white space in mobile mode and you need to scroll to see the site

Tags: css

I have a bug on the WordPress site on Mobile
There is a blank white space and the site opens when you see only the white area and you have to scroll right to see the site
When I run the site without RTL everything works out, the problem is that the site is in Hebrew and I have to RTL
What do you think needs to be changed and where to solve it?
[image: That's how it looks]

Comment: Do you have a URL we can see?

Comment: I'd guess you have margins set up for desktop view that you're not removing in your smallest @medias. It's probably easiest to debug this on a desktop and using your browser's developer tools to select mobile device screen sizes (e.g. the 'device toolbar' in Chrome), then you can inspect the elements left on the page and work out where the space has come from. And whilst we're happy to help, this isn't really a WordPress issue I don't think.

Comment: it sometimes happens in desktop too here is the site address http://tricolad.blog/he/